# Supervisord - Daphne - no module named project

Tags: supervisord, django-channels

I am trying to run django-channels in Ubuntu following official tutorial (https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deploying.html#nginx-supervisor-ubuntu)

Here's my supervisor config file

```
   [fcgi-program:django-c42]
# TCP socket used by Nginx backend upstream
socket=tcp://localhost:8000

# Directory where your site's project files are located
directory=/home/jaga/C42

# Each process needs to have a separate socket file, so we use process_num
# Make sure to update "mysite.asgi" to match your project name
command=daphne -u /run/daphne/daphne%(process_num)d.sock --fd 0 --access-log - --proxy-headers mysite.asgi:application

# Number of processes to startup, roughly the number of CPUs you have
numprocs=4

# Give each process a unique name so they can be told apart
process_name=asgi%(process_num)d

# Automatically start and recover processes
autostart=true
autorestart=true

# Choose where you want your log to go
stdout_logfile=/var/log/django.log
redirect_stderr=true
```

Below is the error from `django.log`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/daphne", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(CommandLineInterface.entrypoint())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/daphne/cli.py", line 170, in entrypoint
    cls().run(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/daphne/cli.py", line 232, in run
    application = import_by_path(args.application)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/daphne/utils.py", line 12, in import_by_path
    target = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 848, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/jaga/C42/./mysite/asgi.py", line 8, in <module>
    django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/asgi.py", line 12, in get_asgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'
```

I don't have any files named `project` so I cant find the cause of the error

Answer (score 0):

My environment variables weren't accessible inside supervisord.
I added the following command to supervisord config file since my variables were in `/etc/environment`

```
bash -c 'source /etc/environment' &&
```